# How setState to array in index? react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

i have in the state an array:

```
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        title: "",
        content: ["",""],
        note_number: "",
        fetch_notes: "",
        img: "",
    }
}
```

so here i set the value to the array:

```
    const {params} = this.props.navigation.state;
    this.setState({title: params.data.title});
    let array_notes = this.state.content.slice();
    array_notes[0] = params.data.content;
    this.setState({content: array_notes});
    this.setState({note_number: params.note_number});
    this.setState({fetch_notes: params.fetch_notes});
```

as you can see, i create a new variable with the slice method, this will create a copy of the original array and with the index zero, i tell him in that index store the content (string) the insert to content, the problem is here where i print the array in the index 1, that should be empty, but it gets the same value as the index zero, i think its bacause the method onchangetext, which is:

```
  <View style = {this.styles.textinput_container}>
                <TextInput style = {this.styles.TextInput_title} placeholder = "Title" multiline = {true} maxLength = {80} value = {this.state.title} onChangeText = {title => this.setState({title: title})}></TextInput>
                <TextInput placeholder = "Content" multiline = {true} value = {this.state.content[0]} onChangeText = {text => this.setState(({content:[text,this.state.content[0]]}))}></TextInput>
                <Text>{this.state.content[1]}</Text>
            </View>
```

Onchangetext function:

```
text => this.setState(({content:[text,this.state.content[0]]}));
```

i dont really understad well this code, because a guy passed it to me, but it should only store in the position zero, why when im printing it

```
<Text>{this.state.content[1]</Text>
```

the index 1 gets the same value as the zero?

Answer (score 1):

Your function

```
text => this.setState(({ content: [text, this.state.content[0]] }));
```

is settings `this.state.content` to an array where the 0th index is equal to `text` and the 1st index is equal to `this.state.content[0]` i.e. whatever was in the 0th index previously

If you want the array to only have one value i.e. the 0th index you can do

```js
text => this.setState(({ content: [text]] }));
```

If you want `text` to replace the 0th index of `this.state.content`, you can do

```js
text => this.setState(state => ({ content: [text, ...state.content.slice(1) ]]}));
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to update any arbitrary index, you could create a generic update function like so

```js
const setIndex = (vals, i, v) => [
  ...vals.slice(0, i),
  v,
  ...vals.slice(i+1)
];
```

and use it like this,

```js
text => this.setState(state => ({ content: setIndex(state.content, 0, text) }));
```

Comment: ok, thanks,, but this is for the first index: text => this.setState(({ content: [text]] }));
what about if I want to set the second index?

Comment: I've added an example of something you could use to update any index. Though personally this doesn't look like a good approach to me.